# how to model a singleton object to table through hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, data-modeling

I have a global config object in my project and there can ever be 0 or 1 instance of this class that i want to persist in db. What is the  best way to do this ? One trick i know here is to have a "constant" field mapped with unique constraint set on it, are there other such ways as this looks a little hacky ?
Here's what i tried :-

```
    @Entity
    public class DTLdapConfig implements Serializable {

        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
        @Id
        private int id;

        @Column(unique=true)
        private boolean singletonGuard;

 // no public setter getter for singletonGuard

 // other code below

}
```

Comment: need more details regarding what you want to do, with something that you have tried :)

Comment: If it's a singleton, why don't you simply decide that it's ID is 1 (or any other constant), instead of auto-generating its ID? To get it, use `session.get(DTLdapConfig.class, 1)`.

Comment: what is the life-cycle of your object? when do you want to load it, who modifies it, when do you want to save it?